# SQL Return corresponding values for duplicated rows in separate column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have over 10K codes that I want to extract from the table to and show Euro and Sterling selling price in separate columns. My code duplicates each code and returns both currencies in 1 column making over 20K rows.

I am not advanced tech guy :-( I am trying to find a better ways of doing things. I browsed through few examples which were less complicated and suggested PIVOT or Dynamic Table functions but I could not understand how to implement it in my code hence I am reaching to you guys. I know you can probably do it with closed eyes.

SQL Code

```
SELECT
    SI.Code AS [Item Code], SI.Name AS [Item Name], 
PLSA.SupplierAccountNumber AS [Supplier Code], SC.Symbol AS [Currency], 
SIS.ListPrice AS [€ Selling Price], PG.Code AS [PG Code]
    , PG.Description AS [PG Name], SIP.Price AS [Standard Cost]
    , CASE WHEN PB.PriceBandID = 129519 THEN '£ Standard'
    WHEN PB.PriceBandID = 1001 THEN '€ Standard'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END AS [Selling Currency Std] 
    , SIS.SupplierStockCode AS [Supplier Stock Code], 
SIStatus.StockItemStatusName [Stock Code Status], SI.AnalysisCode8 AS 
 [Core / Non-Core]
    , SI.AnalysisCode7 AS [Product Chart], SI.AnalysisCode6 AS [Website Product]
FROM StockItem SI
    INNER JOIN StockItemSupplier SIS ON SIS.ItemID = SI.ItemID
    INNER JOIN PLSupplierAccount PLSA ON SIS.SupplierID = 
PLSA.PLSupplierAccountID
    INNER JOIN SYSCurrency SC ON PLSA.SYSCurrencyID = SC.SYSCurrencyID
    INNER JOIN ProductGroup PG ON PG.ProductGroupID = SI.ProductGroupID
    INNER JOIN StockItemPrice SIP ON SIP.ItemID = SI.ItemID
    INNER JOIN PriceBand PB ON PB.PriceBandID = SIP.PriceBandID
    INNER JOIN StockItemStatus SIStatus ON SIStatus.StockItemStatusID = 
SI.StockItemStatusID
```

the result is

```
| Item Code |...   |Selling Currency Std|
----------------------------
|        M1 |      |     €1.00 |
|        M1 |      |     £0.90 |
|        M2 |      |     €5.00 |
|        M2 |      |     £4.50 |
|        M3 |      |     €9.99 |
```

What I want it to be:

```
| Item Code |...   |Selling Currency Std €|Selling Currency Std £|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|        M1 |      |                €1.00 |                 £0.90|
|        M2 |      |                €5.00 |                 £4.50|
|        M3 |      |                €9.99 |                 £8.99|
```

Comment: Check PIVOT support in your dbms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a something like excel's sumif, only sum the value if condition is true. If you have no duplicate for (Item, Currency) the sum will only add up 2 values, one always 0 and the other is the actual SalesPrice in the specific currency.

```
; with ItemPriceList as
    (select
        SI.Code as [Item Code]
        , sum(iif(PB.PriceBandID = 1001, SIP.Price, 0)) as [Selling Currency Std €]
        , sum(iif(PB.PriceBandID = 129519, SIP.Price, 0)) as [Selling Currency Std £]
    from
        StockItem SI
        inner join StockItemPrice SIP on SIP.ItemID = SI.ItemID
            inner join PriceBand PB on PB.PriceBandID = SIP.PriceBandID
    group by
        SI.Code
    )
select
    IPL.[Item Code]
    , IPL.[Selling Currency Std €]
    , IPL.[Selling Currency Std £]
from
    ItemPriceList IPL
    --inner join the additional data for analysis
```

Oh, and don't brother with the additional information, like [Supplier Code], [PG Code], etc. while you're collecting the Sales Price, they can be added later on, that's why I used a CTE.